# Is there any way to detect month change in android calendar view(i.e. when user changes calendar to another month)

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, calendarview

I want to get month shown in calendar view and i cant figure it out. i tried

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                        int dayOfMonth) {
            int d = dayOfMonth;
            int m = month;
            Log.d("month", "" + m);
            String curDate = String.valueOf(d);

        }
});
```

but it only triggers when user click to the days of month. What i want is when user changes the month i want the changed month(i.e. the month shown in calendar view.)
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think from Android's default CalendarView you can't achieve what you want. For this you need to implement your custom calendar or any other library which provides this implementation or provides listeners or gestures for swiping between months. Refer this link if it helps you: 
 [Material-CalendeView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/)

And this is the sample code:

```
 MaterialCalendarView calendarView = new MaterialCalendarView(getActivity());
 calendarView.setOnMonthChangedListener(new OnMonthChangedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {
            //Do something like this
            Date date1 = date.getDate();
     }
 });
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: great it works. thanks bro i was stuck like 3 days in this problem.

Comment: but how do i parse it bro when i log date it gives me like this CalendarDay{2017-8-1}

Comment: Check my updated answer. Now you can do anything with your Date object. :-D