# Android CalendarView how to detect Month change

Tags: android, calendarview

I need to search my database basing the query on the month returned from a CalendarView. My problem is that onSelectedDayChange() event fires only when clicking, actually selecting a date not when the month is changed by swiping CalendarView. 
How to set up something like "onSelectedMonthChange"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with the Android `CalendarView`. Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752408/is-there-any-way-to-detect-month-change-in-android-calendar-viewi-e-when-user).

If you want to do it, you will have to make custom `CalendarView` class which will `extend` `CalendarView` and implement `onGestureListener`. Keep a variable `curMonth` to keep account of your month. Whenever swipe left/right happen, update your `month` variable accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with your suggestion . How to test a fling on my PC?

Comment: @alberto Fling should work on an emulator (PC) as it's not multi-touch gesture. However, I advice mobile device to test gesture related stuff  :-)

Comment: hmm bad start already!  public class FlingCalendaView extends CalendarView implements MyGestureListener {}  show error "there is no default constructor available in 'Android.widget.CalendarView'"

Comment: Make a constructor of your own which will have an argument as context.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to show next and previous months in your calendar based on some click event, then you can do it as:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

//for next month
btnNext.onClick(){
     c.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);
}
//previous month
btnPrevious.onClick(){
     c.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
}
```